# Are any of these sentences grammatically correct and do they make sense? The usage of the verb ADVISE

Tags: verbs

Please tell me which of these are correct:

1. I advise this car.
2. I advise this car to you.
3. I advise this car for you.
4. I advise this car to you to buy.
5. I advise this car for you to buy.
6. I advise you this car.
7. I advise you this car to buy.
8. I advise you for this course.
9. I advise this man to buy this car.
10. I advise your buying this car.

Comment: For starters, none of these are really sentences. No. 8 is a bit of an outlier, should probably be removed.

Comment: If they are not sentences then what are they?

Comment: Yes, they are sentences, but (9) is the only valid one, because you advise a person _to do_ something. I would advise you to use _recommend_ instead in most of the others.

Comment: What I'm getting at is two things - more context would help us answer the question better, and secondly, these are little more than fragments - a real conversation would normally include some 'reason'.

Comment: You think that classifying them as fragments would do any better.... Auch.... This is a syntactic analysis. No big reason is needed this time.

Comment: What @MikeBrockington said. ***We need a specific context***. For example, without context, most native speakers would probably say *I advise this car* isn't idiomatically valid. But ***in certain contexts***, it could be a perfectly acceptable "reduced" form of *I advise [**you to buy**] this car* (if those highlighted elements have been sufficiently strongly ***implied*** by the context).

Comment: I'm ***downvoting*** as well as closevoting - specifically because of example #8, which could be about a completely different use of the verb ***to advise*** (academic course advisors as opposed to people recommending which car you should buy).

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, do you mean that 8 could mean "I recommend you for this course"?

Comment: What we are both saying is that you have nine examples that specifically mention "car" and one that appears to have a completely different topic, for no clear reason.

Comment: Would you rather I had written "I advise you for this car?"

Answer (score 1):

Of the ten options listed, only #9 is even slightly grammatically correct, but even it doesn't seem to match what you apparently want to say.  I would suggest "I advise you to buy this car" to match the object of all your other example sentences.

Please note that this is a *very* direct statement, and is actually quite forceful.  To say "I advise you to {...}" is a statement made from a position of authority, with a great deal of formality. This sentence construction, "I advise you to..." is the sort of thing you would expect your lawyer to say during a dangerous legal situation-- except that the context of buying a car really does not seem to fit the severity level of the expression.

As such, I would further suggest softening the construction of the phrase more by adding the subjunctive "would".

> "I would advise you to buy this car."

Other ways to soften the statement to fit the situation would be to avoid using the word "advise", replacing it with "suggest" or "recommend".

> "I suggest you buy this car."
>
> "I recommend you buy this car."

Or you could restructure the sentence entirely.

> "I think this car would be a good choice."